# Do-loop VBscript...Then run in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Not sure how to phrase this exactly but ill try,
Im making a joke Batch file that creates temp VBS files to perform actions to prank my friend.

Here is the code(ignore the ====names==== i will get rid of those later):

```
:loopall
=====CD OPEN======
:Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
:Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
:do
:if colCDROMs.Count >= 1 then
:For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
:colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
:Next
:For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
:colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
:Next
:End If
:wscript.sleep 5000
:loop
findstr "^:" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs

======Caps lock Spam=====
:Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
:do
:wscript.sleep 100
:wshshell.sendkeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
:loop
findstr "^:" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs

=====Type you have been pranked====
:Set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
:do
:wscript.sleep 100
:wshshell.sendkeys "You have been pranked."
:loop
findstr "^:" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs
goto loopall
```

BUT the places i got my VBS code from were already looped,so it doesnt work right (The temp file never gets deleted.And im guessing it would only loop 1 VBS and never go on to B and C)

I need someone who knows VBScript to help me De-loop The VBS codes so i can have all 3 loop simultaneously through the Batch goto command.

I tried myself but got hit with a bunch of errors on the .VBS files.

Comment: So what you're saying is, you want to..... Loop De-Loop? (⌐□_□)

Comment: Haha yeah I guess,lol,can you help?

Comment: Simply combine everything in one loop by removing all `:do` and `:loop` and leaving just one `findstr`, no?

Comment: Hmmm...this question is blocked by [ESET](http://www.eset.com/int/) - **Threat found!** `VBS/BadJoke.AL` trojan. Had to disable it to see the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this to get you started.

```
::Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
::Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
::Set wshshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

::If colCDROMs.count >= 1 Then

::For i = 0 To colCDROMs.count - 1
::colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject '// CD Open
::Next

::For i = 0 To colCDROMs.count - 1
::colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject '// CD Open
::Next

::End If

::wshshell.SendKeys "{CAPSLOCK}"  '// Caps Lock Spam                
::wshshell.SendKeys "You have been pranked." '// Type message

::WScript.Sleep 5000 '// Sleep for 5 seconds  

:LOOPER
FindStr "^::" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs
GOTO LOOPER

 REM Not sure you need all 3 lines?
 REM FindStr "^:" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs
 REM FindStr "^:" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp3.vbs
```

The other important thing to note is that this (deliberately) causes an infinite loop - you will need to stop it by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, going to the `Processes` tab and stopping the `WScript` process.

Ultimately, and I can't stress this enough  - **Don't play around with these type of scripts unless you know exactly what they do and how to undo/stop them.**

---

You've been warned, use it at your own risk.

Comment: I think this is what you're trying to do - see edit above.

Comment: Ah,i never thought about it from that perspective,YES!! i believe that will indeed work. Thankyou very much.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark as answer if it does work. Got there eventually :)

Comment: Accidentally dropped a line out - edited to correct it - try above

Comment: Perfect. Were done here,lol. i will mark your answer as the solution.